# OpenCV Training the SVM with picture examples Error

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

when training my classifier, i get this error:

Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed) in reshape, file /home/denn/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 802

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/denn/Downloads/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:802: error: (-13) The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed in function reshape

Aborted (core dumped)

I'm working on an Automatic Number Plate Recognition project in C++. all that is left now is train the my SVM.

I resized all my images to a 450 by 450 after researching this but the error persists.
I have studied and looked around but none of the solutions works for me.

any help accorded will be highly appreciated.

```
    // Main entry code OpenCV

  #include <cv.h>
  #include <highgui.h>
  #include <cvaux.h>

  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>

  using namespace std;
  using namespace cv;

   int main ( int argc, char** argv )
  {
cout << "OpenCV Training SVM Automatic Number Plate Recognition\n";
cout << "\n";

char* path_Plates;
char* path_NoPlates;
int numPlates;
int numNoPlates;
int imageWidth=450; //144
int imageHeight=450; //33

//Check if user specify image to process
if(argc >= 5 )
{
    numPlates= atoi(argv[1]);
    numNoPlates= atoi(argv[2]);
    path_Plates= argv[3];
    path_NoPlates= argv[4];

}else{
    cout << "Usage:\n" << argv[0] << " <num Plate Files> <num Non Plate Files> <path to plate folder files> <path to non plate files> \n";
    return 0;
}        

Mat classes;//(numPlates+numNoPlates, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat trainingData;//(numPlates+numNoPlates, imageWidth*imageHeight, CV_32FC1 );

Mat trainingImages;
vector<int> trainingLabels;

for(int i=0; i< numPlates; i++)
{

    stringstream ss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss << path_Plates << i << ".jpg";
    Mat img=imread(ss.str(), 0);
    img= img.reshape(1, 1);
    trainingImages.push_back(img);
    trainingLabels.push_back(1);
}

for(int i=0; i< numNoPlates; i++)
{
    stringstream ss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss << path_NoPlates << i << ".jpg";
    Mat img=imread(ss.str(), 0);
    img= img.reshape(1, 1);
    trainingImages.push_back(img);
    trainingLabels.push_back(0);

}

Mat(trainingImages).copyTo(trainingData);
//trainingData = trainingData.reshape(1,trainingData.rows);
trainingData.convertTo(trainingData, CV_32FC1);
Mat(trainingLabels).copyTo(classes);

FileStorage fs("SVM.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "TrainingData" << trainingData;
fs << "classes" << classes;
fs.release();

return 0;
 }
```

I edited the code and made it like this:

```
  // Main entry code OpenCV

#include <cv.h>
 #include <highgui.h>
 #include <cvaux.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

  int main ( int argc, char** argv )
  {
  cout << "OpenCV Training SVM Automatic Number Plate Recognition\n";
  cout << "\n";

char* path_Plates;
char* path_NoPlates;
int numPlates;
int numNoPlates;
int imageWidth=450; //144
int imageHeight=450; //33

//Check if user specify image to process
if(argc >= 5 )
{
    numPlates= atoi(argv[1]);
    numNoPlates= atoi(argv[2]);
    path_Plates= argv[3];
    path_NoPlates= argv[4];

}else{
    cout << "Usage:\n" << argv[0] << " <num Plate Files> <num Non Plate Files> <path to plate folder files> <path to non plate files> \n";
    return 0;
}        

Mat classes;//(numPlates+numNoPlates, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat trainingData;//(numPlates+numNoPlates, imageWidth*imageHeight, CV_32FC1 );

Mat trainingImages;
vector<int> trainingLabels;


Mat classes = new Mat();
Mat trainingData = new Mat();

Mat trainingImages = new Mat();
Mat trainingLabels = new Mat();

for(int i=0; i< numPlates; i++)
{

    stringstream ss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss << path_Plates << i << ".png";
    Mat img=imread(ss.str(), 0);

    img= img.reshape(1, 1);
    trainingImages.push_back(img);
    trainingLabels.push_back(1);//trainingLabels.push_back(Mat.ones(new Size(1, 1), CvType.CV_32FC1));//trainingLabels.push_back(1);
}

for(int i=0; i< numNoPlates; i++)
{
    stringstream ss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss << path_NoPlates << i << ".png";
    Mat img=imread(ss.str(), 0);

    img= img.reshape(1, 1); //img= img.clone().reshape(1, 1);
    trainingImages.push_back(img);
    trainingLabels.push_back(0);//trainingLabels.push_back(Mat.zeros(new Size(1, 1), CvType.CV_32FC1));//trainingLabels.push_back(0);

}

trainingImages.copyTo(trainingData);
//trainingData = trainingData.reshape(1,trainingData.rows);
trainingData.convertTo(trainingData, CV_32FC1);
trainingLabels.copyTo(classes);

FileStorage fs("SVM.xml", FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "TrainingData" << trainingData;
fs << "classes" << classes;
fs.release();

return 0;
   }
```

but I get this error on compilation:

```
    /home/denn/Desktop/NumberPlateRecognition/trainSVM.cpp:52:27: error: conversion from      ‘cv::Mat*’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Mat’ requested

  /home/denn/Desktop/NumberPlateRecognition/trainSVM.cpp:52:27: error: conversion from   ‘cv::Mat*’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Mat’ requested

 /home/denn/Desktop/NumberPlateRecognition/trainSVM.cpp:53:32: error: conversion from ‘cv::Mat*’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Mat’ requested

  /home/denn/Desktop/NumberPlateRecognition/trainSVM.cpp:55:34: error: conversion from      ‘cv::Mat*’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Mat’ requested

    /home/denn/Desktop/NumberPlateRecognition/trainSVM.cpp:56:34: error: conversion from        ‘cv::Mat*’ to non-scalar type ‘cv::Mat’ requested
 make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/trainSVM.dir/trainSVM.cpp.o] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/trainSVM.dir/all] Error 2
  make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I any advice?

Comment: if m.isContinuous() == false - you can't call reshape on it. the earlier you remove that problem in your pipeline, the better

Comment: where is that? I haven't seen it anywhere. Could you please explain to me what it means and how to remove it? thanks Berak

Comment: [isContinuous](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-iscontinuous)

Comment: the problem is in your data , not in your code. are you using some program to preprocess/resize the images ? it might pad your images , so width is a multiple of 4 ( which is a bad thing here ).

Comment: like robot_sherrick hints below, as soon as you create a new Mat fom the old data, you get rid of the problem. probably even a `img= img.clone().reshape(1, 1);` does the trick

Comment: the only preprocessing I have done is reshaping the images to make all of them the same size with image magick.

Comment: try to save them as .pgm instead of .jpg (or any other format, that does not allow hidden padding)

Comment: Tried with pgm, still same error. am reading up on the suggestion robot_sherick gave so I can try implement it. Note am a newbie in OpenCv :-(

Comment: Tried with pgm, still same error. am reading up on the suggestion robot_sherick gave so I can try implement it. Note am a newbie in OpenCv :-(  update! tried removing padding from all images with image Magick but this didn't help, unless am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As berak pointed out in the comments above, your [`cv::Mat`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-iscontinuous) can become discontinuous in the following instances:

> if you extract a part of the matrix using Mat::col(), Mat::diag() , and so on, or construct a matrix header for externally allocated data, such matrices may no longer have [the iscontinuous()] property.

As they point out in the above reference, create your matrices using [`Mat::create`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#void%20Mat%3a%3acreate%28int%20rows,%20int%20cols,%20int%20type%29) and you won't have this issue.

Update:

So, the function `Mat::clone`, as our friend berak pointed out in the comments above, will do the trick for you.  It calls the function `Mat::create`.  I just tried out the following code, and it worked like a charm.

```
Mat trainingImages;
vector<int> trainingLabels;

for(int i=0; i< numPlates; i++)
{

  stringstream ss;
  ss << path_Plates << "grumpy" << i << ".jpg";
  std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
  Mat img =imread(ss.str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

  if(! img.data )  {
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
  }
  else {
    img = img.clone().reshape(0,1);
    trainingImages.push_back(img);
    trainingLabels.push_back(i);
  }
}
```

However, a few notes, it looks like you might not have the right header file names.  I used the following with OpenCV 2.4.8 on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml/ml.hpp>
```

Also, make sure to compile it with the OpenCV libraries (i.e. opencv_core and opencv_ml).  Hope that helps you in your quest for plate recognition.

Comment: how do I use Mat::create? is there a source that you know of that has more explanation and examples that could be of use? my own search is proving futile